# Issue using directive's scope variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i have a directive defined as follows :

```
.directive('question', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      replace: 'true',
      templateUrl:'scripts/directives/questions/tpl.html',
      link: function($scope, $element,$attrs){},
      controller: function($scope, $element,$attrs,Type,Templates){

          $scope.editButtonVisible = false;
          if($scope.editMode == 'w'){
            $scope.editButtonVisible = true;
          }

      },
      scope: {
        editMode    : '=isReadOnly'
      }
  };
});
```

my issue is that when i try using the variable editButtonVisible with either ngShow or ngSwitch it does not work, for instance the following sample :

```
<ANY ng-switch="editButtonVisible">
  <ANY ng-switch-value="true">
    <button>edit</button>
  </ANY>
  <ANY ng-switch-value="false">
    <h1>No button</h1>
  </ANY>
  <ANY ng-switch-default>
    <h1>Default action</h1>
  </ANY>
</ANY>
```

the button is shown  and both h1 are shown too.

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't need to define another variable for this scenario.

Next, your controller can import '$scope', but there is nothing like '$element', '$attrs' for the controller. You might have confused the function signature with that of 'link' function.

Next, your 'link' function signature is wrong. Although, the controller function is like `controller: function($scope)`, the link function is like this: `link: function(scope, element, attrs)`. There should be no '$' sign.

Take a look at the below fiddle.

[JSFiddle: Toggle enable using scope variable](http://jsfiddle.net/CodeHawkz/gz8jobr8/)

Comment: thanks you, at first it didn't  work because i had a lot of issues with my code so once i cleaned everything it worked fine.

Comment: Great! happy to be of help